# jQuery applying script to multiple select boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, gravity-forms-plugin

I followed this tutorial here that turns a select box into a slider on gravity forms using the jquery UI and it works, however...

https://jsfiddle.net/hirejordansmith/6rapbyn2/

I have 100s of select boxes and I need them all working correctly as the tutorial is only for one select box on the page.

If you have multiple is seems to add all of the select box fields into all of the sliders, any ideas guys?

This is the link I'm working on: https://www.claims.co.uk/test123#gf_1

To get to the slider section select male>head>"Damage to teeth"+"Deafness"+"Epilepsy" and then press next to see the sliders.

This is my code:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    function sliderTooltip( $select, index, $handle ) {

    var index    = Math.max( 0, index ),
        curValue = $selectDesktop.find('option').eq(index).text(),
        tooltip  = '<div class="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-inner">' + curValue + '</div><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div></div>';

    $handle.html(tooltip);

  }

  function sliderConditionalLogic( $select, index ) {
    var index  = Math.max( 0, index ),
        formId = $select.parents( 'form' ).attr( 'id' ).split( '_' )[1],
        $input = $( '#gform_next_button_' + formId + '_2' );
    if( index == 0 ) {
        $input.hide();
    } else {
        $input.show();
    }
  }

    var $selectDesktop = $(".claims-calculator .gfield_select");
    var $sliderDesktop = $("<div id='slider-desktop'></div>")
      .insertAfter($selectDesktop).slider({
        min: 1,
        max: $selectDesktop.find('option').length,
        range: "min",
        value: $selectDesktop[0].selectedIndex + 1,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
          $selectDesktop[0].selectedIndex = ui.value - 1;
          sliderTooltip( $selectDesktop, ui.value - 1, $( ui.handle ) );
          sliderConditionalLogic( $selectDesktop, ui.value - 1 );
        }
      });

    sliderTooltip( $selectDesktop, $selectDesktop[0].selectedIndex, $sliderDesktop.find('.ui-slider-handle' ) );
    sliderConditionalLogic( $selectDesktop, $selectDesktop[0].selectedIndex );

});
```

Comment: As you're trying to apply the same behavior to distinct elements, this seems like a good candidate for making a little jquery plugin. See the part especially which discusses the "each" function: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: Please let me know if I can clarify my answer for you or if it did not solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your code to work for only one select box at a time like you want you will actually have to run a portion of it separately for each select box you have. Right now you are selecting all of your `<select>`'s here:

```
var $selectDesktop = $(".claims-calculator .gfield_select");
```

Perhaps the simplest way to understand and do this would be to duplicate everything after that line so that you have 3 blocks of code (one for each unique `<select>`) but of course this is messy so instead I recommend using the jQuery .each extension and looping through each of your  elements to run the code.

Here is the code I am proposing:

```
$(".claims-calculator .gfield_select").each(function() {
  var $selectDesktop = $(this);
  var $sliderDesktop = $("<div id='slider-desktop'></div>").insertAfter($selectDesktop).slider({
    min: 1,
    max: $selectDesktop.find('option').length,
    range: "min",
    value: $selectDesktop[0].selectedIndex + 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $selectDesktop[0].selectedIndex = ui.value - 1;
      sliderTooltip($selectDesktop, ui.value - 1, $(ui.handle));
      sliderConditionalLogic($selectDesktop, ui.value - 1);
    }
  });

  sliderTooltip($selectDesktop, $selectDesktop[0].selectedIndex, $sliderDesktop.find('.ui-slider-handle'));
  sliderConditionalLogic($selectDesktop, $selectDesktop[0].selectedIndex);
});
```

Now this leaves us with 1 problem left to resolve: in your "sliderTooltip" function you have a reference to "$selectDesktop" which in my .each loop I made an instanced variable (it references a different `<select>` every time it runs). You need it to instead reference the `<select>` that is relevant at the time of execution. I recommend changing to the proper variable that your code is already piping through called: "$select" like so:

```
curValue = $select.find('option').eq(index).text(),
```

Comment: Sorry I had to nip out and get food there.
I get the logic in your code, but I don't think its selecting it right at the moment.
I've added your code in now, the sliders have disappeared just dont know how to target the selects. Would you mind taking a quick look please?
https://www.claims.co.uk/gravity.js

Comment: Not a problem. So you might have reverted it but I'm seeing the same code now that I saw the other day. Regardless, see [this code](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jonahaaron/fccafa79fca6c3e6f080655a93515697/raw/663de9fbcba0fda7eb5c1c82d8de8f69349ebc65/gravity-exp.js) for the full write up of my proposed changes.

Comment: Note that to target the selects I selected them like this: `$(".claims-calculator .gfield_select")` and then I ran `.each(function(){`. While inside those brackets you can find the individual selects with `$(this)`

Comment: That worked thanks so much for your help appreciated!